# How to represent before/after changepoint trends using geom_smooth (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset composed of 3 variables evolving through time. I mapped it using `ggplot2` and `geom_point`. I identified a common changepoint in 2013.
**My goal is to add "lm" trends (before/after the changepoint) for each variable.**
My problem is that I cannot find the way to obtain **2 trends** (before 2008-2013 / after 2014-2019) for each variable on the same graph.

I have the following dataset :

```
year <- 2008:2019
var1 <- c(-50,-98,-162,-310,-387,-550,-577,-670,-857,-989,-1123,-1247)
var2 <- c(-99,-171,-255,-440,-520,-689,-741,-878,-1107,-1238,-1411,-1559)
var3 <- c(-24.5,-58,-80,-209,-242,-364,-384,-448,-586,-664,-788,-876)
ba <- data.frame(year, var1, var2, var3)
```

I mapped my data using the following code :

```
ba.l <- gather(ba, key = var, value = ba_value, -year)
g <- ggplot(ba.l, aes(x = year, y = ba_value, col = var)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)
print(g)
```

I obtain this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZO0j.png)

I tried many things without any success...
**How can I cut those 3 trends (in 2013) in order to have 6 (coloured by variable) ?**

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
year <- 2008:2019
var1 <- c(-50,-98,-162,-310,-387,-550,-577,-670,-857,-989,-1123,-1247)
var2 <- c(-99,-171,-255,-440,-520,-689,-741,-878,-1107,-1238,-1411,-1559)
var3 <- c(-24.5,-58,-80,-209,-242,-364,-384,-448,-586,-664,-788,-876)
ba <- data.frame(year, var1, var2, var3)
#Plot
ba.l <- gather(ba, key = var, value = ba_value, -year)
ggplot(ba.l, aes(x = year, y = ba_value, col = interaction(var,year>2013),
                 group=interaction(var,year>2013))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)+
  labs(color='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(ba.l, aes(x = year, y = ba_value, col = var,
                 group=interaction(var,year>2013))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)+
  labs(color='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
year <- 2008:2019
var1 <- c(-50,-98,-162,-310,-387,-550,-577,-670,-857,-989,-1123,-1247)
var2 <- c(-99,-171,-255,-440,-520,-689,-741,-878,-1107,-1238,-1411,-1559)
var3 <- c(-24.5,-58,-80,-209,-242,-364,-384,-448,-586,-664,-788,-876)
ba <- data.frame(year, var1, var2, var3)

ba_l <- pivot_longer(ba, cols = c(var1, var2, var3))
ba_l <- mutate(ba_l, name = paste0(name, year>=2013))

ggplot(ba_l, aes(x = year, y = value, col = name)) + geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>